# BUG: scheduling while atomic

Tags: linux, kernel

I have just installed Linux (OpenSUSE), and when start the OS, I get an error

```
BUG: scheduling while atomic: systemd_udevd plymounthd...
```

what does it mean?

Comment: Assuming you are not asking about `scheduleing` (should be `scheduling`), can you indicate what distribution and what hardware you are using

Answer (score 2):

This message is what it looks like: it's the indication of a bug. Specifically, it comes from the Linux kernel. It's a fairly generic symptom of a badly-written driver.

This bug indicates a kernel bug: nothing outside the kernel can cause this to happen unless the kernel is buggy in the first place. The only other possibility is a hardware failure: bad RAM can cause just about anything; also, some drivers may not be fully protected against buggy hardware.

As a user, apart from changing your RAM if it's failing, there's nothing you can do to fix this bug. You may be able to work around it by arranging not to use the specific feature or program or settings that trigger this bug, if you manage to figure out how to reproduce it.

The first step to diagnose this bug is to check the kernel logs. If you can log in, run the command `dmesg` or read the kernel log file (often `/var/log/kern.log`
but this depends on the distribution). This may give you a clue on how to avoid the bug, and it's vital information if you report the bug to a developer. Make sure to copy-paste the full set of messages if you can, and if you're unable to copy-paste, reproduce the error exactly, including proper spelling, capitalization, punctuation, spacing, etc.